# Type parameters in type and data constructors

Tags: haskell

If I understand correctly,

```
data Int = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ...
```

All things on the right-hand side are just values.

In the following,

```
data Maybe b = Nothing
             | Just b
```

Do `b` in `Maybe b` and `b` in `Just b` mean the same thing? To me, it looks like that `b` in `Maybe b` is a **type variable**, and `b` in `Just b` is a **value variable of type b**.

Comment: `Just b` is a value of type `Maybe b`.

Comment: The type of the `Just` constructor is `b -> Maybe b`. So when used as a constructor, `b` is a parameter with a value of type `b`. `b` of the LHS refers to a type parameter. `b` of the RHS refers to a value parameter. Since a type is a set of associated values, I'd say both refer to the same thing, but from different levels of abstraction. Anyway, my definition is still fuzzy, sorry.

Comment: @n.m. `Just b` is a value of type `Maybe t` where `b :: t`. those mental shortcuts can be very confusing to new learners.

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/Type#Data_declarations ; https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.2 ; http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses ; https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Type_declarations#data_and_constructor_functions ; etc. search for "haskell data declaration".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data Maybe b` means that the type is generic, and that `b` is the generic type variable.

`Just b` does, indeed, indicate that one of the ways you can create a value of `Maybe b` is by supplying a value of the type `b`.

```
Prelude> Just "foo"
Just "foo"
Prelude> Just 42
Just 42
```

Here, `Just "Foo"` has the type `Maybe String`, so the type type variable `b` is `String`. In Haskell, types are variables as well.

If you, however, examine the type of `Just 42`, you'll see that it's still abstract:

```
Prelude> :t Just 42
Just 42 :: Num a => Maybe a
```

This means that it could be any `Maybe a` as long as `a` is an instance of the `Num` typeclass. So in this case, the type is still 'variable'.

(The first example, `data Int`, doesn't compile...)

Comment: `Just b does, indeed, indicate that one of the ways you can create a value of Maybe b is by supplying a value of the type b.` This helps. Thanks. Though, I will tend to consider the type of `Just 42` as concrete rather abstract.

Comment: "generic" in Haskellspeak is "parametric", methinks. tyvar is just tyvar, no "generic" qualifier is needed here.